# Adding lines and legends in R

Tags: r, legend

I am trying to figure out how to add both points and lines (in color) to a legend in R.

What I want to plot is something like this:

```
x = 1:10
y = sin(x)
z = cos(x)

plot(x,y,type='l',lty=2,col="blue")
points(x,z,pch=19,col="red")

#I know this legend command doesn't work, but I just want to explain what I want
legend("topleft",c("x","y"),pch=19,lty=2,col=c("red","blue")
```

So as you can see, I would like to be able to have both points and lines (with the correct type and coloring) in the legend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You NA values as other argument for `pch=` and `lty=`.

```
legend("topleft",c("x","y"),pch=c(19,NA),lty=c(NA,2),col=c("red","blue"))
```

Comment: When it allows me to I will accept your answer.  Worked great!  Thanks!